# How do I get three monitors working on an Nvidia GTX 590?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Some weeks ago I bought the latest and greatest graphic card from Nvidia (GTX 590) I previous used AMD 6950 that supported my 3 monitors perfectly.

I tried to install the GTX 590 with Ubuntu 11.04 but had some issues with the default graphic driver. Instead of spending hours of investigation I decided to wait for the release of Ubuntu 11.10 with an hope that my GTX 590 multi monitor setup was supported nativly.

After 5 days with problem shooting I still don’t have my three monitors up and running. I'm able to configure twin-view with 2 monitors but not able to "hock on" the third monitor.

Are there anyone that has successfully configured Ubuntu 11.10 with a GTX 590 and a 3 monitor setup? Or do I need to go back to my AMD 6950 card and see that I have spent £ 500 on something that's not working for me?

I have tried to use the additional drivers(Post release drivers) that can be installed in Ubuntu. I have not yet tried the latest drivers from nvidia.com on 11.10 (Tried this for 11.04 without success)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

I did the following:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --no-sli --no-twinview --separate-x-screens --xinerama
```

And that did the trick for me. You have to disable sli to get Xinerama to work and tvinview only worked with 2 monitors anyways. So this is the best I have got out of it so far. Just had to re-arrange the monitors with the Nvidia X Server Setting -utility. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this and I worked exept for 1 problem. 3D unity failed to load and same with compostion. I tried to add this to the config but it still complained about not able to load the composite. E.g the Cairo bar didn't load and the unity became unstable